# Not able to load the Microsoft.Bcl.AsyncInterfaces assembly in powershell

Tags: powershell, nuget

I am using the NuGet package "Npgsql" in powershell by using:

```
 Add-Type -Path "Npgsql.8.0.0/lib/netstandard2.0/Npgsql.dll"
```

> "Exception calling ".ctor" with "1" argument(s): "Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Bcl.AsyncInterfaces, Version=7.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51'. The system cannot find the file specified.\n"

So I tried to install and load the Microsoft.Bcl.AsyncInterfaces NuGet package, as suggested in other answers and I am getting the error:

> "Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Bcl.AsyncInterfaces, Version=7.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51"

How can I proceed further to resolve this error?

Comment: Yes the dll file is at the correct location and other libraries are getting loaded successfully.

Answer (score 0):

Look at what dependencies you are installing, we had this exact error and saw that POSH-SSL was updated 2 days ago which caused it for us. so we rolled that back to a previous version.